# How ot force EF Database First to use IList<T> instad of ICollection<T> for 1:N navigation properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am working on a WPF project and I try to create editable grid for an Entity's navigation property that is a 1 to N relation.

Now when I try to edit the value in the `DataGrid` then I get the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.

But if I do the following in the constructor of the viewmodel it works fine:

```
this.A.A1 = new List<A1>(this.A.A1);
```

I generated my model with EF 5.0 Database First.

Is there any way to make EF generate a type of IList as 1:N Navigation property?

Comment: I doubt it. The defining characteristic of `IList<T>` is that it has members that are specific to the underlying array. Is there a point to exposing a collection of entities as an array? Perhaps. If so, just slap `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` onto the `DbSet<T>` property in the context and go to town.

Comment: @KeithPayne: Sorry to disagree, because it is working. "The defining characteristic of IList<T> is that it has members that are specific to the underlying array." It is maybe true, but here the members are references so I still working with the same objects.